# ¿Como enviar un dato a javascript desde php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

Resulta que estoy tratando de pasar un valor de `PHP` a `Javascript` para que me haga una validación si ya existe cierto dato.

El script de `PHP` hace su trabajo si el dato existe devuelve `1` y si no devuelve `0`, el problema es que no se como tomar ese valor de nuevo en `Javascript`.

Les dejo el código para ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

**HTML:**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario de registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
    <script src="../js/llenar.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
    <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
        <h2> Crear capitanes</h2>
        <div class ="contenedor-input">
            <input type = "number" id = "cedula" name = "cedula" placeholder = "Cedula" class = "input-100" required>
            <input type = "text" id = "nombre" name = "nombre" placeholder = "Nombres" class = "input-48" required>
            <input type = "text" id = "apellido" name = "apellido" placeholder = "Apellidos" class = "input-48" required>
            <input type = "text" id = "user" name = "user" placeholder = "Usuario" class = "input-48" required>
            <input type = "text" id = "pwd" name = "pwd" placeholder = "Contraseña" class = "input-48" required>
            <select name = "congregacion" id = "cmbCongregacion" class = "input-100" required>
            </select>
            <input type = "submit" value = " Registrar capitan" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar">
        </div>      
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btn-enviar");
    btnEnviar.onclick = enviarForm;
    var cedula = document.getElementById("cedula");
    cedula.onblur = repetido;
    $.post("../php/llenar1.php",function(data){
        $("#cmbCongregacion").html(data);
    });

}

function repetido(){
    var cedula = document.getElementById("cedula");
    var valor;
    valor = cedula.value;
    $.post("../php/repetido.php", {cedula: valor}, function(data){
        $("#cedula").html(data);
        alert(html(data));
    });
}
```

**RESPUESTA SCRIPT PHP:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de que la petición se ejecuta correctamente, los datos que devuelve el servidor llegan como parámetro a la función que se ejecuta al finalizar la petición (success), en tu caso has llamado al parámetro `data`

```
$.post("../php/repetido.php", {cedula: valor}, function(data){
    $("#cedula").val(data); // para elementos de formulario (inputs, select, etc) no se usa `.html()` si no `.val()`
    alert(data);
});
```

Por lo cual hacer un alert(data); debería de mostrarte dicha respuesta.

**NOTA:** es importante que desde **PHP** estés devolviendo el valor por medio de un `echo`

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Para ver una variable de PHP en Javascript basta con imprimirla dentro del mismo javascript. Necesito que expliques mejor que es lo que exactamente quieres. Cual variable quieres ver en javascript? Por favor edita tu pregunta o comenta en mi respuesta. Aquí la solución

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var variablejs = '<?php echo $tuvariable;?>'
</script>
```

Comment: Yo no quiero imprimir la varible que me manda php lo que quiero es validarla y si esta es igual a 1 entonces deberia mostrame un mensaje diciendo que la cedula que intento ingresar ya existe y si es igual a 0 pues que me deje de terminar el proceso de registro

Comment: @FamiliaValenciaHdz La respuesta entonces en base a tu comentario es la de CamiloVasquez. Lo que sucede es que el titulo de tu pregunta es muy ambiguo en conjunto con la explicación. Es por ello que se puede interpretar de varias formas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se presenta porque estas usando la funcion `html` de jquery para llenar el input, debes cambiarlo por `val`:

Lo tienes asi:

```
$("#cedula").html(data);
```

Debe ser asi:

```
$("#cedula").val(data);
```